# C++: delete values from map in "for each" loop

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, foreach, function-pointers

For a `std::vector<double*> v;` I can delete the `double`s by calling

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), (void(*)(void* a))operator delete);
```

Now, if I have `std::map<int, double*> m;` instead, can I do a similar thing without using an explicit loop, boost or non-standard STL extensions? I.e. what is `???` in

```
std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), ???);
```

Comment: Will `m.clear()` do what you want?

Comment: Since the container apparently "owns" the pointee objects, you might want to use a Boost [ptr_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html). With that, erasing an item from the map will also destroy the pointee object.

Comment: `operator delete` is not `delete`, never use it this way.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: What would then be the correct way?

Comment: Also, I suspect that `void(*)(void*)operator delete` is undefined behaviour when used this way. If you `new` a `T`, you must `delete` a `T*`.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: You need a functor that'll call `delete` on a pointer. Either a C++11 lambda expression, or `delete_ptr` from Boost.Lambda or just write your own.

Comment: @Cat++: Can you give a pointer what the difference between `delete` and `operator delete` is?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: 0x1247182A.

`operator delete` is a counterpart to `operator new`, and it only deals with allocation of raw memory. `new`/`delete` additionally deal with construction (they do allocation via `operator new`/`operator delete`) — they call ctors and dtors, which is necessary for correct behaviour. Your first snippet only works because you've used a fundamental type.

Comment: For an example of the dtor *not* being called: http://ideone.com/Y7bWH

Answer (score 10):

Don't bother. `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<double>>`. No more need to `delete` manually and you can just `clear()` the map. Smart pointers > explicit deletion *every time*.

Comment: I'm maintaining existing code, so changing the type won't be easy. Apart from that I found the question interesting by itself. (In the end I could just write a simple for loop.)

Comment: I agree that this is the best solution, but note that `clear()` has the effect of reducing the `size` of the map to 0, which isn't exactly matching the behaviour specified in the OP's vector example.

Comment: Scott Meyers in his "Effective C++" says it's terrible bad idea to use auto_ptr with STL containers. unique_ptr is much better then auto-ptr, but I think it's still in most cases better ti use shared_ptr

Answer (score 6):

If you are using C++11, you can use the range-based for.

```
for(auto& pair : m) delete pair.second;
```

If you are using a pre-C++11 standard, you can use functors:

```
struct delete_second {
  void operator()(std::pair<int, double*> p) { delete p.second; }
};

...

  std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), delete_second());
```

Answer (score 3):

With C+11 you can do:
`std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [](std::pair<int,double*> p) { delete p.second; });`

Comment: Might be an advantage to declaring lambda parameter as reference: `[](std::pair<int, double*>& p) { ...}`.

Answer (score 0):

What's the use of deleting p.second without removing the entry from the map?